# Where is the return URL option in the Paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

According to Paypal's documentation, one sets a return URL like so:

1. Log in to your PayPal account at https://www.paypal.com. The My
   Account Overview page appears.
2. Click the Profile subtab. The Profile Summary page appears.
3. Under the Selling Preferences column, click the Website Payment
   Preferences link. The Website Payment Preferences page appears

I am trying to test this in the sandbox, but when I go to the Profile Summary page, it looks like this:

[image]

There is no "Website Payment Preferences" that I can see.

Is this not possible in the sandbox? Or has it moved?

Comment: That's because you've got a 'Personal' account. Create a 'Business' account and you'll see this option appear in the Profile.

Comment: Ah, whoops. Put that as an answer and you've got yourself some easy rep. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Useful but just change #1 to

1. Go to the sandbox( https://developer.paypal.com/ ) website and log in; click Test Accounts; select your test Seller/Business account; click "Enter Sandbox Test Site"

Answer (score 2):

Sandbox can send you the transaction data (also called Instant Payment Notification) to a specific url. With Instant Payment Notification, PayPal sends payment notification messages with encrypted code to the specified URL for each payment you receive. Follow the instructions below to setup Instant Payment Notification.

1. Go to the sandbox( https://developer.paypal.com/ ) website and log in to your account(business account).
2. Click "Profile" at the top of the page.
3. Click "Instant Payment Notification Preferences" in the Selling Preferences column.
4. Click "Edit IPN Settings."
5. Enter the notification URL and select "Receive IPN messages."
6. Click "Save."

Comment: I know this is old but this is for `IPN` which is for notifying the merchant of any payments done. While the `returnUrl` is a link where user is redirected to after the payment is successful.